# Which is better of the two: effects happening before rolling, or after rolling?

Tags: system-agnostic, optimization, statistics

Plenty of systems use both types of abilities "before a participant A rolls, add bonus/effect to opposed number/roll of Participant B" or "If a participant A would succeed, add bonus/effect to opposed number/roll of participant B and re-evaluate the situation"

I have been wondering which type of ability is the better one for players to use, or are they equal when considering optimization, system mastery and probability.

I think both kinds are present in the latest 5e dnd. For example you can see within fighter's archetype, battle master superiority die maneuvers to have both kinds. This is just for referencing an example but I want to keep this system neutral.

Comment: This is not opinion-based. One option is strictly, mathematically superior to the other.

Comment: I think this question would benefit from a stricter definition of "better". Better for the players, in terms of character power? Simpler for the game system overall? Easier for the flow at the table?

Comment: I think the answer for all of those is yes.  Characters only use the ability when necessary (more powerful), the game system does not have to deal with multiple opportunities to change the roll (simpler), and it is smoother at the table, because you don't have any "I meant to use my ability" or "hmm, should I use my ability here" questions, because making a relatively informed decision is quicker and smoother than making a relatively uninformed decision (easier/quicker flow at the table).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latter is strictly better. In cases where you have limited resources involved, you can choose whether or not to use them based on the roll, i.e. how much you think you need the effect. For example, only using a bonus when the roll isn’t good enough but close, or only using a penalty when the roll succeeds but only barely—cases where the bonus or penalty actually changes the result.

Whether or not you know the target number is irrelevant—knowing it allows you to be precise in your judgment, but even if you don’t, you can usually tell when using the effect is worthwhile, or at least tell when it clearly won’t be. For example, when a natural-1 is an auto-fail or a natural-20 is an auto-success, clearly expending some resource to apply a bonus or penalty is a waste of time.

When there aren’t limited resources involved, it doesn’t matter (and should just be a passive bonus).